# Keeping button selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following three likert scales:

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="...">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <a class="btn btn-link disabled" disabled>Not Dangerous</a>
    <button id="fear" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-1">1</button>
    <button id="fear" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-2">2</button>
    <button id="fear" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-3">3</button>
    <button id="fear" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-4">4</button>
    <button id="fear" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-5">5</button>
    <a class="btn btn-link disabled" disabled>Extremely Dangerous</a>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="...">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <a class="btn btn-link disabled" disabled>Not Dangerous</a>
    <button id="danger" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-1">1</button>
    <button id="danger" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-2">2</button>
    <button id="danger" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-3">3</button>
    <button id="danger" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-4">4</button>
    <button id="danger" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-5">5</button>
    <a class="btn btn-link disabled" disabled>Extremely Dangerous</a>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="...">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <a class="btn btn-link disabled" disabled>Not Dangerous</a>
    <button id="control" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-1">1</button>
    <button id="control" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-2">2</button>
    <button id="control" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-3">3</button>
    <button id="control" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-4">4</button>
    <button id="control" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-5">5</button>
    <a class="btn btn-link disabled" disabled>Extremely Dangerous</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

and the following script:

```
$(".btn.btn-default").click(function () {
        if (this.id == 'fear') {
            $('#fear').val($(this).text());              
        } else if (this.id == 'control') {
            $('#control').val($(this).text());               
        } else if (this.id == 'danger') {
            $('#danger').val($(this).text());                
        }
    });
```

However after selecting the first likert scale, and a selection is made on the second likert scale the selection of the first is lost. See gif:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to have more than one button in a focused state (ie, highlighted) per page?  I don't think it is.  Buttons generally don't indicate a selection state, rather the highlight indicates which form element has focus right now.

Comment: Those duplicate IDs aren't helping matters.

Answer (score 1):

First, you shouldn't have duplicated IDs. Change them for the below:

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="...">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <a class="btn btn-link disabled" disabled>Not Dangerous</a>
    <button id="fear1" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-1">1</button>
    <button id="fear2" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-2">2</button>
    <button id="fear3" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-3">3</button>
    <button id="fear4" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-4">4</button>
    <button id="fear5" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-5">5</button>
    <a class="btn btn-link disabled" disabled>Extremely Dangerous</a>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="...">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <a class="btn btn-link disabled" disabled>Not Dangerous</a>
    <button id="danger1" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-1">1</button>
    <button id="danger2" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-2">2</button>
    <button id="danger3" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-3">3</button>
    <button id="danger4" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-4">4</button>
    <button id="danger5" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-5">5</button>
    <a class="btn btn-link disabled" disabled>Extremely Dangerous</a>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="...">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <a class="btn btn-link disabled" disabled>Not Dangerous</a>
    <button id="control1" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-1">1</button>
    <button id="control2" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-2">2</button>
    <button id="control3" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-3">3</button>
    <button id="control4" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-4">4</button>
    <button id="control5" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-5">5</button>
    <a class="btn btn-link disabled" disabled>Extremely Dangerous</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Second, you can add an active class to the selected button, but first remove it from all its siblings:

```
$(".btn.btn-default").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active').end().addClass('active').val($(this).text());  
});
```

Please have a quick look at the [docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute) for more information about ID uniqueness in the DOM. This will save you a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake 1: the id values for every items must ve unique.
Your mistake 2: you have to seperate point selectors by type using class or something

I think this will help you.

```
www.codepen.io/airsakarya/pen/RaBMyE?editors=1010
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you **should not** use ids to select multiple elements. Ids are used to specify single dom elements, use class instead.

Second, probably you are messing up with bootstrap's javascript.

Try to follow this [example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons) to obtain a native behaviour with radio buttons

Answer (score 1):

[Active Buttons Demo](http://codepen.io/antibland/pen/KzBoBz)

[image]

**HTML**

```
<section class="buttons" role="group"> 
  <button>button 1</button> 
  <button>button 2</button> 
  <button>button 3</button>
</section>

<section class="buttons" role="group"> 
  <button>button 1</button> 
  <button>button 2</button> 
  <button>button 3</button>
</section>
```

---

**JavaScript**

```
function setActiveButton() {
  $(this)
    .css({ background: "tan" })
    .siblings()
      .css({ background: "inherit" })
}

$('[role=group]').each(function(index, button_group) {
  $('button').on('click', setActiveButton);
});
```